# Can Panresponder inherit Touchable touch event?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

In react native I have a button which on pressIn opens a modal. In the modal I have a View with Panresponder handles, that allows to drag a box up and down inside the modal.

This is working fine but I have to do an additional touch when the modal has opened, in order for the Panresponder View to pickup the touch and start dragging. Is there a way to pass the touch event to the modal or have the Panresponder View inside the Modal pickup the touch while a finger is still on the sceen?

Example code:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false
  };
  render() {
    <View>
      {/* When this is pressed...  */}
      <TouchableOpacity onPressIn={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: true })}>
        <Text>Open & start dragging</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {/* Is there a way to capture the touch event right away?  */}
      <DragModal visible={this.state.modalVisible} />
    </View>;
  }
}

class DragModal extends Component {
  translateY = new Animated.Value(0);
  panresponder = PanResponder.create({
    // Ask to be the responder:
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
      null,
      {
        moveY: this.y
      }
    ])
    // ...etc
  });
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal visible={this.props.visible}>
        <View {...this.panresponder.panHandlers} style={styles.container}>
          <View
            style={{
              ...styles.dragHandle,
              transform: [{ translateY: this.translateY }]
            }}
          >
            <Text>Draghandle</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```